# Want to add a horizonal Line along with series value in bar graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

hey I am really unsure how to add line like this. i tried few google search to do that but doesn't work and change the orientation of graph. Any help will be appreciated [image: 65]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the technique outlined [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2011/07/21/create-convincing-visualizations-by-adding-reference-lines-to-your-excel-charts/), you can achieve this as follows.

Create a 2x2 table as shown in green in this image (location of the table is not important):

[image]

Select the range of this small table and Copy the range. Select the chart object, then go to Home>Clipboard>Paste>Paste Special and configure like this:

[image]

Note that it is important that you select the chart before choosing paste special.

Your chart will look strange to begin with:

[image]

Click on either of the bars just added, then right-click and choose "Change Series Chart Type". Change the Chart Type for the newly added bars to "Scatter with Smooth Lines":

[image]

You now have this bar on a secondary axis. If you don't see a secondary horizontal axis, use Chart Design>Chart Layouts>Add Chart Element>Axes>Secondary Horizontal. You should now have this (though the secondary horizontal may be at the bottom of the chart):

[image]

Right click the new horizontal axis and select 'Format axis'. Change the Axis bounds minimum to 0 and maximum to 1.

Next, align the secondary vertical axis with the primary vertical axis. Again, right-click the axis and choose "Format Axis". For my example, I needed to:

1. Tick/Check 'Values in reverse order'
2. Change the axis bounds minimum to 8900 (the minimum strike price)
3. Change the axis bounds maximum to 11300 (the maximum strike price)

After doing that, I could click the secondary vertical axis and delete it.

For the secondary horizontal axis, deleting it will delete the reference series, so instead, change the font colour to be the same as the background. This is the result:

[image]